# Как очистить текст в AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, if

Добрый день, подскажите

алгоритм работы приложения такой.

Первый запуск приложения

при нажатии на кнопку onClickPhoto появляется AutoCompleteTextView далее переменной name = mAutoComplete.getText().toString(); присваивается значение при нажатии второй раз на кнопку onClickPhoto проверяется условие и срабатывает остальной код.

Но всё это работает только при первом запуске приложения если продолжать работать в нём не перезагружая то при нажатии на кнопку onClickPhoto действие сразу будет переходить к проверки условия как сделать что бы всё повторялось снова ?

```
 public void onClickPhoto(View view) {

    name=null;//пытаюсь обнулять
    mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.VISIBLE);
    name = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();



    //button3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {рабочий код}
```

Comment: Совершенно ничего не понятно

Comment: Э-э-э... Наверное вам надо не ссылку на текст очищать, но текст в mAutoComplete...\

Comment: @ЮрийСПб немного перефразировал вопрос, но я так уже делал mAutoComplete = null и у меня начало падать приложение

Comment: Так вы не текст внутри mAutoComplete очищаете, а сам mAutoComplete. Вам надо попробовать что-то типа `mAutoComplete.setText(null);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это правильный ответ.

Comment: @VargSieg, написал в ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб всегда найдётся то кто тебя поймёт ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не текст внутри `mAutoComplete` очищаете, а сам `mAutoComplete`, т.е. переменную, содержащую ссылку на него. Вам надо попробовать что-то типа

`mAutoComplete.setText(null);`

Для очистки текста, внутри `mAutoComplete`